# Wordpress Custom Field Value from MoreFields not returning value

Tags: php, wordpress, field, meta

hello everyone here is the snippet of code I am having problems with...

```
<?php $ReleaseDate = meta('dvdReleaseDate'); ?>
```

If I return the value for $ReleaseDate, I get nothing...

I have also tried....

```
<?php $ReleaseDate = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'dvdReleaseDate', true); ?>
```

Nothing works..I really need help. I am using Wordpress 3.0.1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to access this data at the most basic level:

```
<?php echo 'DVD Release Date:'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dvdReleaseDate', true);?>
```

Make sure you use this call somewhere where your $post object is accessible -- ie, within the loop. If you're using this somewhere outside the loop (for example, in functions.php), declare your $post object beforehand like this:

```
<?php 
global $post;
echo 'DVD Release Date:'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dvdReleaseDate', true);
?>
```

If you still get no output from this, it means either:

1. You are referring to your custom field by the wrong name
2. This custom field has not been set for this post, or
3. You are trying to use this function somewhere where your $post object is inaccessible

If #3 is in question, try something like this:

```
<?php
echo 'if there is data in $post, it will print here:';
print_r($post);
echo 'DVD Release Data:'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dvdReleaseDate', true);
?>
```

If your post object doesn't print, then you're experiencing #3. If it does, but there's no custom field output, it's one of the first 2.